# What application protocol are mobile apps like Draw Something using?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

If i would be doing something like Draw Something,Zynga Poker etc,what are the application protocol considerations and choices should i make?Are apps like that building on http,which means the apps itself is essentially a web browser, or they are using a custom application protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are most likely using HTTP. All the mobile app clients connect to a central server which tracks what games are being played and the various pieces of information about that game. Custom protocols are more common when it comes to Peer-2-Peer applications but due to the number of firewalls and NATs out there and the lack of understanding on how to alter their firewall settings very few applications are written this way anymore.

Comment: What are the extra considerations should I take when developing this kind of apps from developing normal web app.Any resources would be just fine.

Comment: The biggest consideration is the fact that you must keep the 3rd party server up and running at all times otherwise no one can play your games. Aside from this the differences are mostly positive. It allows each client to play their turn without the other client being present, it allows for better security as you can hide data in the neutral 3rd party rather than letting the adversarial clients handle everything. That's all I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

As Spencer says, they are all using HTTP calling a web service to save and load data. They are not essentially a web browser though as they are not rendering or downloading HTML. They are using the protocol to pass data, but the data could be JSON, XML or proprietary. It is not HTML though.

I would add that if you are going about developing your own apps that access a centralized web service, you will need to either a) write your app using a web services framework (I recommend RestKit or AFNetworking for iPhone) and then write your server side API code (using whatever language you like) and then figure out where to host your server somewhere (I would recommend EC2), or b) use one of the new API Server services like StackMob or Parse that handle creating and hosting your API for you and then you just worry about writing the app.